# How to prevent JavaFX ContextMenu items from being focused on TAB key pressed?

Tags: javafx-8

I have a few TextFields. I would like to go to the next TextField when I press the TAB key.
This works fine when the ContextMenu associated with the TextField is not shown. When the ContextMenu is shown, pressing the TAB key focuses the items in the ContextMenu. I don't want that behaviour.

I tried this:

```
setAllChildrendTraversable(false, ((Parent) tf.getContextMenu().getSkin().getNode()).getChildrenUnmodifiable());

//...

    static void setAllChildrendTraversable(boolean traversable, ObservableList<Node> childs) {
        for(Node node : childs) {
            if(node instanceof Parent) setAllChildrendTraversable(traversable, ((Parent) node).getChildrenUnmodifiable());
            else node.setFocusTraversable(traversable);
        }
    }
```

but it doesn't give the wanted result.

Would this be the correct way to access all the Nodes in the ContextMenu?
Or, is my approach to this problem is way wrong?

Answer (score 0):

but this does...:

```
setAllChildrendTraversable(false, ((Parent) tf.getContextMenu().getSkin().getNode()).getChildrenUnmodifiable());

//...

    static void setAllChildrendTraversable(boolean traversable, ObservableList<Node> childs) {
        for(Node node : childs) {
            if(node instanceof Parent) setAllChildrendTraversable(traversable, ((Parent) node).getChildrenUnmodifiable());
            node.setFocusTraversable(traversable);
        }
    }
```

I just had to remove the else keyword...

Sry for making you loose some time.